# VSC throwing expected a ')'

Tags: c++, class

```
Bulb::Bulb(int[4] pins){
    pinr = pins[0];

}
```

This code is the constructor block for a class that I created called bulb, VSC throws the error

```
Expected a ')' with this piece of code on the int[4] pins
                                                      ^
```

Comment: `int pins[4]`. Although that will be passed as a pointer, not an array.

Comment: `Bulb::Bulb(int[4] pins){` - > `Bulb::Bulb(int* pins){`

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the simple class structure:

```
class Bulb {
    int pinr;

public:
    Bulb(int*); // first method
    Bulb(int[]); // second method
};
```

**First method:** declare parameter correctly, `int[] pin` is invalid.

```
Bulb::Bulb(int pin[]) { // dynamically fixing array size + correct way
    pinr = pin[0];
    std::cout << pinr << std::endl;
}
```

**Second method:** pass as a pointer, no problem here.

```
Bulb::Bulb(int* pin) { // as a pointer
    pinr = pin[0];
    std::cout << pinr << std::endl;
}
```

And the driver code:

```
int main(void) {
    int tArr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    Bulb b(tArr); // outputs 1 by both methods

    return 0;
}
```

---

Debugging the program would give you:

**Debugging First Method:**

[image: Debugging the first method]

**Debugging Second Method:**

[image: Debugging the second method]